# React Typescript: MUI Accordion - how to implement handleChange for an array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, accordion

A beginner here so here goes:-
Trying to implement MUI Accordion for an array, the example doesn't show how to implement handleChange() for an array, at the moment it displays the accordion but it is not responding to onChange() at all.

My hunch is that I will have to implement a state hook with a tuple to bind individual accordion components, but I am at lost how to implement this.

I've put my implementation in Demo.tsx (original sample was pulled from MUI Accordion)

[My sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizedaccordions-material-demo-forked-mke7rf?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Tried console logging the expanded panel and it's giving me expanded panel's name that is panel1,2,3 etc. What's the issue you are facing because it seems like onChange is firing up correctly because the state is getting updated

Comment: I managed to find an article that is pretty close (https://dominicarrojado.com/posts/how-to-create-your-own-accordion-in-react-and-typescript-with-tests/) and copied that. Now my accordion can open/close, but the icon beside the Accordion doesn't change (button up/down)